# Wordpress wont startup

Tags: troubleshooting

So far I've narrowed down the execution trail to

`index.php` -> `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` ->

```
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {
    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

->

```
 if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php') ) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' );
```

-> `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` -> `wp_not_installed();`

The execution doesn't get any further than this and I can't find where `wp_not_installed()` is defined. I don't know why it's led up to that method/function in the first place because I've already installed and set Wordpress up. Any help appretiated...

Comment: Are you getting an error/message page? Or just a whitescreen? Is this a multisite install?

Comment: `wp_not_installed` is defined in `wp-includes/load.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `max_execution_time = 300` inside my `php.ini` resolved it.